# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB

Tags: java, android, recursão

Estou fazendo um algoritmo que converte um [bitmap](/questions/tagged/bitmap) deixando-o em tons de cinza.

Consegui fazer usando for mas gostaria de fazer de maneira recursiva.

---

## Usando for (Esta funcionando bem)

```
//BUTTON - ON CLICK . . .
public void go(View v){
    //BM_3 É UM BITMAP, VARIAVEL GLOBAL QUE JÁ POSSUI UMA IMAGEM EM SEU CONTEUDO . . .
    bm_3 = bm_3.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    for (int x = 0; x < bm_3.getWidth(); x++){
        for (int y = 0; y < bm_3.getHeight(); y++) {

            String hex = Integer.toHexString(bm_3.getPixel(x, y));

            if(hex.length() == 8) {
                String hexX = "#" + convert_Hex_to_grey("" + hex.charAt(0) + hex.charAt(1),
                                                        "" + hex.charAt(2) + hex.charAt(3),
                                                        "" + hex.charAt(4) + hex.charAt(5),
                                                        "" + hex.charAt(6) + hex.charAt(7));

                bm_3.setPixel(x, y, Color.parseColor(hexX));
            }
        }
    }
    //IMG É UMA IMAGEVIEW . . .
    img.setImageBitmap(bm_3);
}
```

---

Com base no algoritmo acima, tentei implementar o mesmo de forma recursiva. Porém, esta apresentando erro de `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1038KB`

---

## Usando recursão (java.lang.StackOverflowError)

**RECURSÃO**

```
private Bitmap grey_scale(int x, int y, Bitmap bm_3) {
        //IF PARA PERCORRER TODO Y . . .
        if (y < bm_3.getHeight()) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(bm_3.getPixel(x, y));
            if (hex.length() == 8) {
                String hexX = "#" + convert_Hex_to_grey("" + hex.charAt(0) + hex.charAt(1),
                                                        "" + hex.charAt(2) + hex.charAt(3),
                                                        "" + hex.charAt(4) + hex.charAt(5),
                                                        "" + hex.charAt(6) + hex.charAt(7));


                bm_3.setPixel(x, y, Color.parseColor(hexX));
            }
            //O ERRO OCORRE NESTE RETURN ! ! !
            return grey_scale(x, y+1, bm_3);

        }
        //IF PARA PERCORRER TODO X, ZERANDO Y A CADA TROCA DE X.
        if (x < bm_3.getWidth()) {
            return grey_scale(x+1, 0, bm_3);
        }
    //RETORNA BITMAP
    return bm_3;
}
```

**BUTTON ON CLICK QUE CHAMA RECURSÃO**

```
public void go(View v){

    bm_3 = bm_3.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
    //FAZ RECURSAO DENTRO DE UMA THREAD . . .
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //CHAMA A RECURSAO
            bm_3 = grey_scale(0, 0, bm_3);

            //VOLTA PRA THREAD PRINCIPAL PARA ATUALIZAR O IMAGEVIEW . . .
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    img.setImageBitmap(bm_3);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: Qual o tamanho da imagem?

Comment: O tamanho da imagem é 5.577 bytes, dando 788 por 788 pixels

Comment: A profundidade aproximada é de 621 mil chamadas recursivas. Não deve ter configurado o tamanho da stack para isso. Creio que só ajeitar o tamanho da stack não ajeita para casos maiores.

Comment: Como configura o tamanho dela?

Comment: Cada chamada acrescenta pelo 12 bytes na pilha só de argumento, sem contar as informações extras de estrutura de chamada de função. A maioria das chamadas também acrescenta pelo menos 4 bytes de referência à variável local `hex`. Talvez o compilador seja inteligente ao ponto de soltar a referência a `hex` antes de fazer a chamada recursiva.

Comment: `-Xms` eu acho. Mas você precisa ter uma ideia do quanto vai consumir, ou testar até não dar mais stack overflow

Comment: `-Xss` é com o tamanho da stack, `-Xmx` é o tamanho inicial da heap; mais detalhes aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700459/4438007

Comment: tentei este = Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize) . Mas mesmo colocando 80m, ele ta erro.

Comment: tentei com uma imagem menor, 252x252 e deu o mesmo erro

Comment: Está rodando pelo eclipse, linha de comando, outra ide ou como?

Comment: Pelo Android Studio

Comment: Pelo que vi, a JRE é livre para definir o tamanho da stack, tomando como referência uma sugestão do que é passado como argumento. Também não sei qual a relação entre a stack da thread secundária e a da principal. Também não sei se é dependente de plataforma

Comment: nesse caso, eu acho que tentar usar os argumentos da máquina virtual Java não vai ajudar.

Comment: Já tentou com uma imagem de 1 pixel de altura? Só para garantir que não é erro no algoritmo?

Comment: Fiz algo semelhante isso quando estava testando com a imagem grande printava a cada troca de linha, ele trava na linha 2. Mas ele chega a começar ela. Na imagem menor, ele trava na linha 55 (com a Thread) com limite de 80m

Comment: tenta uma imagem menor e mais controlada. Por isso o 1 pixel

Comment: Pode ser recursão indireta? Por em uma pilha e processar o resultado? A vantagem desse modo é que a pressão fica na parte dinâmica da memória

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema aqui é o tamanho da recursão. Sua recursão é de aproximadamente 621 mil chamadas, dada a imagem de 788 x 788.

Cada chamada recursiva faz pelo menos a inserção dos argumentos da chamada na pilha. No caso, são dois inteiros e uma referência; os inteiros são 4 bytes cada, a referência é de 8 ou 4 bytes (8 bytes para 64 bits e 4 bytes para 32 bits). Portanto, se põe no mínimo 12 bytes para cada chamada recursiva. Assim, não considerando outros fatores, o mínimo necessário para a stack é de uns 10 ou 12 megabytes só de argumentos da chamada recursiva. Quem sabe o quanto mais de outras informações?

Enfim, talvez com 64 megabytes de stack? Para determinar esse valor, o argumento de máquina virtual `-Xss 64M` define isso. [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3700459/4438007)

> Bem, o AP está com o problema executando no Android Studio, então tentar fazer esses *tweaks* com a JVM pode não resultar em nada.

---

PS: pouco antes de terminar a escrita desta resposta, vi que setar o tamanho da stack na thread não deu certo. Vou inspecionar mais um pouco e então editar a resposta com o que achar