# Como evitar estouro de memoria com recursividade

Tags: java

Eu tenho uma função que é chamada recursivamente, como evitar estouro de memoria ??

```
int cont = 0;

public void recur() {
    recur();

    cont ++;
    System.out.println("Chamado: " + cont);
}
```

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/237151/64969

Comment: O que você está tentando fazer com isso?

Comment: Basicamente eu pego todos os links de uma pagina, e depois chamo a função para pegar todos os links de cada pagina de cada link, e assim recursivamente.

Comment: @LucasCarezia você pode fazer isso com navegação em grafos, mas isso é assunto para outra pergunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisará adicionar uma cláusula de saída. Por exemplo verificando se count == 10.000.

Outra opção que poderá acontecer naturalmente é que acabará a memória da máquina, ou caso esta tenha MUITA memória, o valor de count pode ser maior que o valor máximo de Integer. [Integer.MAX_VALUE]

Comment: Assim, se cada função recursiva ocupar um único byte de memória (ocupa muito mais, na verdade), você usaria 2GB só para chegar nesse nível de profundidade de chamada recursiva. Acho que supor esse valor do máximo inteiro foi esticar e muito a baladeira...

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa de um critério de saída para a recursão.

Comment: Sim. Só isso. Pondo isso não ocorrerá estouro de pilha

Comment: Na verdade, seria adequado também ter uma prova/demonstração/conjectura de que se chega ao caso base da recursão

Comment: Tem uma saida, mas basicamente é quase infinito.